Problema con la validación de formularios usando JavaScript
Estoy desarrollando una función en JavaScript para validar formularios en mi sitio web, pero estoy teniendo dificultades con la lógica de validación. El formulario debe verificar que los campos obligatorios no estén vacíos y que el formato de ciertos campos (como el correo electrónico) sea correcto antes de enviar los datos al servidor.
He intentado implementar la validación usando un enfoque basado en eventos y funciones de validación específicas para cada campo del formulario, pero parece que no se ejecutan correctamente o no estoy capturando los errores de manera adecuada.
A continuación, incluyo un ejemplo simplificado del código que estoy utilizando:
...
function validarFormulario() {
    // Lógica de validación aquí
}

document.getElementById('formulario').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    validarFormulario();
});

...
Me gustaría recibir orientación sobre cómo mejorar mi enfoque actual o si hay alguna mejor práctica recomendada para realizar la validación de formularios en JavaScript de manera efectiva.

Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Muestra un [repro] del problema en cuestión, y haz una pregunta específica, ya que las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas.

No hace falta usar eventos, esto ya viene por defecto en html como sus atributos. Te recomiendo leer mas sobre html formularios, ahi encontraras lo que es "required" para el caso de campos obligatorios y el formato de los elementos como el hot/gmail y etc... por cierto, agrega en onSubmit en el  para poder gestionar el envio de datos. Saludos!

Creo que te faltó incluir tu actual lógica de validación, has puesto un simple comentario, por lo cual no se ve lo que hayas intentado.

de paso.. sabes que por mas que valides el front, tenes que volver a validar absolutamente todo en el back, no?

Puedes optar por las validaciones de html, sin necesidad de javascript, solamente poniendo atributos, por ejemplo:

El atributo required para validar que el campo no esté sin rellenar.

<input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" required>


El atributo type="email" comprueba que es un email.

<input type="email" id="email"/>


El atributo pattern, puedes poner una expresión regular para validar el campo.

<input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4} />

Para más información puede consultar en este enlace:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation
